# How can I make an apex:inputField disabled?

Tags: visualforce

`apex:inputField` does not have an attribute called `disabled`.
 How can I get an `apex:inputField` to be disabled?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An easy and always work workaround:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!onOff}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!someField}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(onOff)}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!someField}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

With a `{!onOff}` variable and `reRender` behavior, the field behavior can be controlled just as you actually need.

Comment: I think you mean to use "rendered" instead of "reRender"

Answer (score 9):

The reason is because this [component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) responds to the read-only state of the field it is bound to (for example if the users profile does not permit editing of the field) via the **value** attribute.

> **Note:** Read-only fields, and fields for certain Salesforce objects with complex automatic behavior, such as Event.StartDateTime and Event.EndDateTime, **don't render as editable** when using . Use a different input component such as apex:inputText instead.