# How to make <apex:inputText> field conditionally read-only without Javascript

Tags: visualforce, html, inputtext, read-only

I would like an input to be conditionally read-only, but I cannot find a way to make a boolean HTML attribute like *html-readonly* conditional within VisualForce. I am avoiding Javascript to remove the attribute mainly because I am new to VisualForce and want to see what I can do with pure VisualForce (minimal JS).

I can't use:

```
<apex:inputText html-readonly="{!makeItReadOnly}" value="{!foo}"/>
```

Because browsers evaluate any value (including *false*) for a boolean attribute as true.

My current work-around isn't particularly clean (though accomplishes my goal):

```
<apex:inputText rendered="{!makeItReadOnly}" value="{!foo}"/>
<apex:inputText html-readonly="true" rendered="{!!makeItReadOnly}" value="{foo}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normal apex:inputText fields, use the `disabled` attribute:

```
<apex:inputText disabled="{!makeItReadOnly}" value="{!foo}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I had seen [How Can I Make An Apex Input Field Disabled](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/how-can-i-make-an-apexinputfield-disabled) and hadn't tried it with `<apex:inputtext>`