# Making Picklist Field not editable depending on some condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

testfield__c is a picklist value and I want to make it non-editable if it is an US Account and not a business profile. I am doing in this way but it is hiding the field but not making it non-editable.
I tried removing the apex: inputField and it worked but it is failing for other Accounts (UK etc.)

```
<apex: pageBlockSection title="{! ($Label.MyAccount)}" collapsible="false" id="AccountSectionId">
    <apex: outputField value="{! account. testfield__c}" rendered="{!!if ((isUSAccount && isSBusinessProfile), true, false)}"/>
                    <apex: inputField value="{! account. testfield__c}" rendered="{! if ((isBusinessProfile &&! isUSAccount), true, false)}"/>
```

Can anyone let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: Look at this post : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118069/how-to-make-apexinputtext-field-conditionally-read-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two Boolean variables, you have a total of four discrete outcomes: false/false, false/true, true/false, and true/true. You've only written logic for two of the four possible outcomes; the remainder will not show any field at all.

You also have a few bugs:

```
{!! IF(...
```

The extra `!` is treated as a NOT operator, so you're actually inverting the logic.

Generally speaking, instead of writing `{!IF(..., TRUE, FALSE)}`, you should just write the condition: `{!...}`, which is easier to read. I also recommend using `NOT(...)` instead of `!`, simply because it's more obvious within a formula.

It appears that you really wanted to do this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!account.testfield__c}" rendered="{!isUSAccount && NOT(isBusinessProfile)}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!account.testfield__c}" rendered="{!NOT(isUSAccount) || isBusinessProfile}" />
```

Using this pattern, we've covered our four possible conditions:

```
          Business Profile?
            TRUE   FALSE
           +------+------+
      TRUE | EDIT | R/O  |
 US?       +------+------+
     FALSE | EDIT | EDIT |
           +------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. 
If US account is TRUE and Business Profile is TRUE it should be Read only R/O. The upper row should be R/O and lower row should be EDITABLE.

Answer (score 0):

**apex:selectList** has a **disabled** attribute that you can use instead of rendered.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm