# Disabling apex:inputField component with html passthrough attribute

Tags: visualforce, inputfield

I'm getting the input using `<apex:inputField>` (must be `inputField` rather than `inputText` to enforce FLS). The `disabled` attribute is not supported for the `<apex:inputField>` tag, so I'm trying to use an html passthrough attribute  from the custom controller:

```
html-disabled="{!booleanVariable}"`
```

Based on the boolean value I'm planning to enable and disable the field. However, when I try to use `html-disabled="true"` or `html-disabled="true"` or `html-disabled=""` every values always make this input field disabled.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your design to display disabled values.

Rather than disabling the `apex:inputField` better to use `apex:outputField` using proper `rendered` condition.

Most of the scenarios like disabling a inputField lookup normally not possible. So, this kind of design will solve the purpose.

Here is an example of lookup field:

```
<apex:panelGroup id="theGroup" rendered="{!isEnabled}">
    <apex:inputField id="AccountId" value="{!opportunityObj.AccountId}"/>
</apex:panelGroup>

<apex:panelGroup id="theGroup2" rendered="{!NOT(isEnabled)}">
    <apex:inputText value="{!accountObj.Name}" disabled="true"/>
</apex:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Hope this helps me to choose a different option.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. How about below. It works as expected, but do you see anyother implication on this.  <apex:inputField value="{!todo.Remainder_Email__c}" rendered="{!show}" /> 
          <apex:inputField value="{!todo.Remainder_Email__c}" rendered="{!!show}" html-disabled="true"/>

Comment: see, some inputField satisfies properly, like text, email, phone types, but some others could create issues, so idea is, whatever supports properly you could leverage `html-disabled="true"` otherwise, take the above approach

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, any value for the disabled attribute will disable the field.

You can wrap the input field in a conditionally-rendered <apex:outputPanel>. Do something like this so that only one inputField is shown at a time.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! booleanValue}">
    <apex:inputField html-disabled="true" /> (or maybe apex:outputField here)
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!booleanValue}">
    <apex:inputField />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32254/how-can-i-make-an-apexinputfield-disabled).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Hope this helps me to choose a different option.